# SwiftUI passing Core Data between Views Error

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have a List of Core Data elements I can add. I want to be able to edit them. For that I have an "edit Sheet" View. But when I try editing the element the app crashes and I get the error "Thread 1: "-[Item setTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002479a80""
I recreated the error here:

```
struct ListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    @State var showEditItemSheet = false
    @State var itemToEdit = Item()
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                ListItemView(item: item)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        itemToEdit = item
                        showEditItemSheet.toggle()
                    }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showEditItemSheet, content: {EditItemView(item: itemToEdit, showEditItemSheet: $showEditItemSheet)}
        }
}

struct ListItemView: View {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    @ObservedObject var item: FetchedResults<Item>.Element
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.title)
    }
}

struct EditItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    @State var item: FetchedResults<Item>.Element
    @Binding var showEditItemSheet: Bool
    @State var title = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Title", text: $title)
            Button(action: {
                item.title = title //<- Here I get the error
                saveContext()
                showEditItemSheet.toggle()
            }, label: {Text("Save")})
        }
    }
    private func saveContext() {
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let error = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try and declare the item as `var item: Item` in EditItemView

Comment: I did this but this didn't fix my error, but thank you for the help!

Comment: Hi there! Your "Item" is a class (specifically, an NSManagedObject subclass), but @State only works for editing structs. In your EditItemView, try changing the declaration to `@ObservedObject var item: Item`.